# Django: Form field size

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms

In Django Templates, how do i specify the size of a field

This is my form class:

```
class PstForm(forms.Form):
     hours = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(6,6),(24,24),(48,48)], widget=forms.Select(attrs={'size':'3'}))
```

however this still renders a rather long field

how do i limit the size?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could try adjusting the CSS: `attrs={'style': 'width:10px'}`, (or `'class': 'some-class'`, etc).

Comment: Better still: `attrs={'class': 'narrow-select'}` and then in your CSS file `.narrow-select { width: 10px; }`. Don't mix code and presentation.

Comment: You can also do it by overriding __init__ .....  http://stackoverflow.com/a/7621370/1445649