# Django form multiple select box size in template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a template:

```
    ...
    <form action="/reportform/" method="post">
    <p><label>Aircraft system:</label>
    <br>{{ Querry.system }}
    ...
```

it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtO8z.png)

How can I set a Size option for this box? for example, 10.

Comment: Personally, I would size the textbox using CSS

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the attrs attribute to define the size.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    system = forms.ChoiceField(choices=SYSTEM_CHOICES,
        widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'size':'40'}))
```

Sometimes, it is useful to override the widget in the forms **init** method.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    <snip>
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['system'].widget = forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'size':'40'}))
```

Comment: I'm using the standard Select widget. When I set a size attribute the field become high (like size do in select html https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_size.asp). What can i do to have a fixed width? Thank you

Comment: @fabio this question is 8 years old. I can't help you in the comments. Please ask a new question.